# Dapper em ralacionamento 1-1 onde na classe não tem a chave estrangeira

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

Quando se trabalha com ORM é comum (Será obrigatório?) que se criem as classes de modelo como se fossem um espelho das tabelas do banco. Porem tenho um caso diferente e queria saber se o *dapper* funciona dessa forma. No banco tenho as tabelas. `Produto` e `Fornecedor`

```
Fornecedor:

nome varchar(50)
tel  varchar(11)
cpf  varchar(11) PRIMARY KEY

Produto:

codebar    varchar(13)
nome       varchar(50)
preco      money
custo      money
estoque    int
fornecedor varchar(11) FOREIGN KEY ProdutoToFornecedor(fornecedor) REFERENCES (Fornecedor.cpf)
```

**Obs: Ignorem o SQL, é fictício apenas para fins de demonstração.**

A classe `Produto` tem o atributo do tipo `Fornecedor` mas não tem um atributo que representaria a chave estrangeira com o fornecedor.

```
public class Fornecedor
{
    public string Nome {get; set;}
    public string Tel  {get; set;}
    public string cpf  {get; set;}
}

public class Produto
{
    public string     CodeBar   {get; set;}
    public string     Nome      {get; set;}
    public decimal    Preco     {get; set;}
    public decimal    Custo     {get; set;}
    public int        Estoque   {get; set;}
    public Fornecedor Fornec    {get; set;}
}
```

Como pode ser visto `Produto` tem uma propriedade do tipo `Fornecedor` mas não tem uma outra que seria a chave estrangeira para a tabela `Fornecedor`. Honestamente nunca entendi a necessidade disso. Se um objeto `Produto` terá uma propriedade que é um objeto do tipo `Fornecedor` que por sua vez já possui a propriedade *cpf* que é a chave primária da tabela, pq eu ainda precisaria ter um atributo em `Produto` que se refere a chave estrangeira para `Fornecedor`? Ou seja:

```
public class Produto
{
    public string     CodeBar   {get; set;}
    public string     Nome      {get; set;}
    public decimal    Preco     {get; set;}
    public decimal    Custo     {get; set;}
    public int        Estoque   {get; set;}
    public string     FornecId  {get; set;}
    public Fornecedor Fornec    {get; set;}
}
```

A mim isso parece redundante.

Para se usar ORM, no caso o Dapper existe alguma maneira de fugir disso? Ou seja, usar a propriedade `Fornec` que é um objeto `Fornecedor` e já tem o atributo *cpf*?

Comment: Não é necessario a FK. Dá uma olhada: [How to map a complex object using Spliton and Types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273494/how-to-map-a-complex-object-using-spliton-and-types)

Comment: Tem sim. Quando fizer a consulta faz ela retornar uma dto ou ObjectValue apenas com os campos que precisa e na estrutura mais adequada. O link do Matheus ajuda a entender como fazer isso.